# How to add options to a select tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a bit of JavaScript that, on the click of a button, adds a  tag filled with options. The options will be defined with an array called "roster". What I would like to see is a  dropdown that has options for sanchez, ronaldo, and ozil.

```js
var roster = [
  "ozil",
  "sanchez",
  "ronaldo"
];

var reps = null;
var dropdown = null;
var scorerOption = "<option value='" + reps + "' class='scorerOption'>" + roster[reps] + "</option>";

function makeDropdown () {
  dropdown = "<select class='scorer'>" + String(scorerOption).repeat(roster.length) + "</select>";
  document.getElementById("rawr").innerHTML = dropdown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="rawr"><button onclick="makeDropdown()">Select a player</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you may notice, the  and  tags appear, but all have innerHTML's and values of "undefined". How can I change that so it displays the names sanchez, ronaldo, and ozil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the array and for each element in the array, create and insert a new `option`.

You should also not use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`), see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** for why.

Lastly, it's generally better to create dynamic elements with the DOM API call of `document.createElement()`, rather than build up strings of HTML as the strings can become difficult to manage and the DOM API provides a clean object-oriented way to configure your newly created elements.

```js
var roster = [
  "ozil",
  "sanchez",
  "ronaldo"
];

// Work with your DOM elements in JavaScript, not HTML
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", makeDropdown);

function makeDropdown () {
  // Dynamically generate a new <select> element as an object in memory
  var list = document.createElement("select");
  
  // Configure the CSS class for the element
  list.classList.add("scorer");
  
  // Loop over each of the array elements
  roster.forEach(function(item){
    // Dynamically create and configure an <option> for each
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.classList.add("scorerOption");
    opt.textContent = item;
    // Add the <option> to the <select>
    list.appendChild(opt);
  });

  // Add the <select> to the document
  document.getElementById("rawr").appendChild(list);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="rawr"><button id="btn">Select a player</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I actually figured out the problem on my own. I simply needed to update the page after converting the dropdown to a string. From there, it all worked out.

Comment: @J.Smith Glad it worked out for you, but you should know that your solution is pretty inefficient and doesn't follow best-practices.